# digest auth fails using postman on marklogic that runs a digestbasic app server

Tags: curl, basic-authentication, marklogic, postman

I am trying to develop some custom rest api in MarkLogic and want to use postman(chrome plugin) REST Client to do some testing.

I have setup postman to make a GET call to a existing REST endpoint of MarkLogic. Seems I cant get the `digest auth` to work when running from Postman...?

Postman call exported in curl :

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="", nonce="", uri="/users", response="71ecc7a954d031fa5eb02a45f258f37d", opaque=""" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 745c4f5f-34d5-075c-6011-ef54e88588fd" 'http://cluey-app-ml1:8050/users'
```

If I do the same curl command directly from the terminal, but without the postman specific stuff, that works:

```
curl -v --digest --user admin:admin -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://cluey-app-ml1:8050/users'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.178.113...
* Connected to cluey-app-ml1 (192.168.178.113) port 8050 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'admin'
> GET /users HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: cluey-app-ml1:8050
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* Server MarkLogic is not blacklisted
< Server: MarkLogic
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="public", qop="auth", nonce="c2e2f63fa5f8674884388a22f6dc6bec", opaque="8ed963a93f01cd6d"
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 209
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host cluey-app-ml1 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://cluey-app-ml1:8050/users'
* Found bundle for host cluey-app-ml1: 0x1ee5990
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host cluey-app-ml1
* Connected to cluey-app-ml1 (192.168.178.113) port 8050 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'admin'
> GET /users HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="public", nonce="c2e2f63fa5f8674884388a22f6dc6bec", uri="/users", cnonce="OWZkYzE5OTI2OWJmYmVjZDAwMGI5ZWUzMDAwMTcxNTg=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="d88c8094402c2b2225eb11ba0d0ece88", opaque="8ed963a93f01cd6d"
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: cluey-app-ml1:8050
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server MarkLogic is not blacklisted
< Server: MarkLogic
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 512
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
* Connection #0 to host cluey-app-ml1 left intact
[{"user":{"id":"952187958352252312", "name":"hugo5", "description":"sccss generated user"}}, {"user":{"id":"1585487239190988150", "name":"jimmy", "description":""}}, {"user":{"id":"7026453114226409808", "name":"joe", "description":""}}, {"user":{"id":"952187958274822997", "name":"hugo4", "description":"sccss generated user"}}, {"user":{"id":"952187958197393682", "name":"hugo3", "description":"sccss generated user"}}, {"user":{"id":"952187958119964367", "name":"hugo2", "description":"sccss generated user"}}]
```

UPDATE [2]
What seems strange that from the terminal is seems that curl first also fails with a 401 but tries again and then succeeds???

So digest works from the terminal, now I need to find the exact settings for postman to match...when in postman selecting `digest auth` I get a ton of options...

```
Connection       Keep-Alive
Content-Length   209
Content-Type     text/html; charset=utf-8
Keep-Alive       timeout=5
Server           MarkLogic
WWW-Authenticate Digest realm="public", qop="auth", nonce="c33989a614d57699abb0d0bf6d6ca56d", opaque="8b7438e3f6432e3e"
```

Questions:
1) Can anyone confirm they have succesfully used Postman against a Marklogic 8 app serverrunning digest authentication and succeeded?
2) Can anyone point me to the right parameters to be set in Postman for a succesfull call to MarkLogic?

hugo

Comment: Hugo,  see some other comments below Geert's post. But also please keep in mind that when testing that if you try digest, then basic, then digest again,the step from basic to digest may have invalidated the passwords.  the link in your post above explains it under the digest section. This does not sound like root cause for you - but I just thought I would mention it as it can confuse the situation even more.

Comment: facing similar issue.
It seems that your app/server has Http Digest Auth implemented correctly (based on your curl logs) . Usually http clients will automatically do authentication if credentials are provided or give you popup in case of Browsers.Authentication process may require multiple HTTP requests which are seamlessly made by most clients (This is apparent in your logs as well, in first request server challenged back with 401 and curl made second request automatically as it already had creds ). The problem is with postman unlike most clients its not making that second request.

Answer (score 2):

Basic authentication is not enabled by default on MarkLogic HTTP app servers. Switch it from `digest` to `digestbasic` or `basic`.

HTH!

Comment: Hi Grtjn, the HTTP app server is in `digestbasic` (checked). Otherwise the second curl command, dirrectly from the CLI would not run... right? This could also be a postman issue? Can anyone confirm a postman call with basic-auth works against a MarkLogic database?

Comment: `digestbasic` should be good enough to make it work. The second curl call uses `--anyauth`, which makes curl do an auth challenge first, at which MarkLogic will respond with which auth method to try again. Anyauth works well if you are unsure whether it is digest or basic that is used..

Comment: Could it be that curl suppresses that Authorization header? Also, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to use postman with MarkLogic basically, we use swagger.io to define our REST API, which is nice, I can import swagger REST def into postman which is nice, I can generate node.js REST call from postman which is also nice... now postman doesnt let me post... man ...

Comment: to find out what cURL succeeded with, run it in verbose mode. you should see first a 403 forbidden on the digest request and then the next successful call. the actual data used in the header for the successful call will then be visible.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Geert's reply, you may find this [article](https://garyrusso.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/how-to-add-authentication-to-marklogic-app/) from [Gary Russo](https://www.linkedin.com/in/garyrusso) interesting. Section 7 even shows how to to use the header value if you want app-level security.